# Missing slash after moving site to subfolder

Tags: htaccess, migration

After I moved Wordpress to a subfolder, I'm getting the following error at Chrome console:

```
GET http://www.mydomain.comwp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.5.4 net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

See? It's missing a "/" after the domain name.

What's the best approach to solve this? 301 redirects on htaccess seems very intrusive, is there any configuration I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by logging in into admin panel and saving site URL with a trailing slash at the end.

Answer (score 0):

add this line anywhere in the wp-config.php file:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com/');
```

It solved the problem for me.